# What do I roll to cast a summon with pre-determined base attack bonus?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, eldritch-invocations

I am playing a warlock in my current campaign and I selected earthen grasp for one of the invocations. Earthen grasp comes with its own base attack bonus:

Earthen Grasp:

> Treat the arm as a Medium creature, with a base attack bonus equal to
>   your caster level and a Strength of 14 +2 per three caster levels (16
>   at 3rd level, 18 at 6th level, and so on).

Looking at this, it doesn't seem to require any sort of roll since the strength bonus is always pre-determined. In that case, what would I need to roll in order to summon/cast an earthen grasp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to roll anything at all to **summon** it; that’s just something you can do, whenever you want, as much as you want. The stats given in the description are for the sake of figuring out the bonuses on any rolls **that the arm makes**. So you know its BAB and its Strength and can figure out attack rolls, grapple checks, and so on.

Comment: I see. In order to check if the arm has grappled the opponent or not, do I need to roll for D20 + Arm Strength modifier vs D20+enemy's strength modifier?

Comment: @UniQuadrion The grapple rules are way more complicated than that, I’m afraid. You can find them [here](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#grapple), though fair warning, I’m still apologizing to the DM for the last time I forced us to use them. They are weird, counter-intuitive, and complicated, though at least *earthen grasp* doesn’t apply any **extra** complications—it works just like any other Medium creature with its BAB and Strength.